# Sitemap - Flooring Function & listener on WP-Forms form isn't working

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, form, function, evergage

Issue: Form submit isn't capturing MCP data

On our flooring page https://www.silvaris.com/products/flooring/ there must be a bug in the function and/or listener. Can you please help?

Listener:

```
 {
                name: 'Flooring',
                action: 'Flooring',
                isMatch: () => /flooring/.test(window.location.href),
                listeners: [
                    Evergage.listener('submit', '#wpforms-form-2404', () => {
                        return requestQuote("wpforms-2404-field_", "Request A Quote [Flooring]")
                    })
                ]
            },
```

Function

```
 const requestQuote = (a, b, c = 8) => {
        const firstName = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}0`)[0].value;
        const lastName = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}0-last`)[0].value;
        const emailAddress = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}2`)[0].value;
        const phone = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}3`)[0].value;
        const companyName = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}1`)[0].value;
        const productsOfInterest = Evergage.cashDom(`#${a}5`)[0].value;
        const amountOfTruckloads = Evergage.cashDom(`[name="wpforms[fields][${c}]"]`).filter(':checked').val();
        if (validateEmail(emailAddress)) {
            if (Evergage.cashDom('input.wpforms-error').length == 0) {
                Evergage.sendEvent({
                    name: b,
                    action: b,
                    user: {
                        attributes: {
                            firstName,
                            lastName,
                            emailAddress,
                            phone,
                            companyName,
                            productsOfInterest,
                            amountOfTruckloads
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```